# Why CWM gets wiped after reboot on Samsung Galaxy Note?

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note

I recently acquired a GT-N7000 handset and tried to root it using [this method](http://rootgalaxynote.com/galaxy-note-root/how-to-root-ics-on-galaxy-note-gt-n7000-no-computer-required/). I successfully flashed CWM and then rooted the device.
It was all good until I went back into Recovery and found out that the CWM is gone and stock recovery is back in place!

I tried reflashing CWM but every time same thing happened after reboot. I just wonder how should I make CWM to stick around?

Comment: Some phones check the checksum of the installed recovery on each boot, and then revert to stock if they found it not matching. Maybe you check [this guide on TheUnlockr](http://theunlockr.com/2012/03/27/how-to-root-the-galaxy-note-and-flash-clockworkmod-recovery-without-increasing-the-flash-counter/)? If it works out, I'll convert my comment to an answer, including a raw excerpt.